# SwiftUI: Strange empty popover near TextField

Tags: swiftui

Each time when I write character in TextField - displayed empty popover near the field.

[image]

It is displayed only on last MacOS/SwiftUI on few computers, but cannot be reproduced on older OS/SwiftUI.

Reproduced on:

macOS: 12.2 (21D49) + 12.2.1

xCode: 13.2.1 (13C100)

Looks like it does not reproduces on 12.2b

Anyone know how to fix it?

```
HStack {
    VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 12) {
        Text("Username or email:")

        Text("Password:")
    }
    
    VStack {
        // REPRODUCED ONLY HERE
        TextField  ("Username or email",    text: $email)

        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
    }
    .frame(width: 190)
}
.padding(.bottom, 15)
```

---

Update:

- It is can be reproduced on macOS  12.2.1
- It opens "empty popup" with size of last opened context menu - if I click on password field it's opens passwords context menu and after this I will see:

[image]

## UPD:

### Bug does not reproduce on `macOS Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400)`

Comment: I can't reproduce it on macOS 12.2b and Xcode 13.2.1

Comment: @ChrisR thanks for info

Comment: This issue still occurs to me on macOS 12.4 and Xcode 13.4.1 (13F100). Quico's answer removed the popover but I couldn't find a way to remove the "Passwords…" popover.

Comment: Any luck fixing this?  Still happens to me

Comment: @conorgriffin I cannot reproduce bug on macOS 13.0.1 (22A400) Ventura

Comment: I'm on 12.6 but still happens

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce this issue with macOS 12.3 and Xcode 13.3. Explicitly setting the `NSTextContentType` of the `SecureField` (via `.textContentType(.password)`) fixed it for me.

Comment: I noticed this doesn't always work. In my case, my form was in a custom view, which is part of a sheet, which still showed this empty popover. However this is the closest answer I found for a fix to this problem.